# Average case running time of quick sort

Tags: algorithms, asymptotics, runtime-analysis, quicksort

How to show that the quick-sort algorithm runs in $O(n^2)$ time on average ?

Because on average, the expected running time is in $O(n\log n)$. The algorithm should not be in exponential time.

Comment: For $O(nlog(n))⊂O(n^m)$ we need $m\gt 1$, otherwise it is not true. BTW, average time and expected time are the same.

Comment: If you already know that quicksort has expected running time $O(n\log n)$, then in particular, you know that it has expected running time $O(n^{1+\epsilon})$ for all $\epsilon>0$, since $n\log n = O(n^{1+\epsilon})$ for all $\epsilon > 0$.

Answer (score 1):

It suffices to show that Quicksort runs in time $f(n) = O(n^2)$ *in the worst case*, since this immediately implies that it also runs in at most $f(n)$ time on average.

The recurrence equation that describes the worst-case running time for Quicksort is
$$
T(n) = T(n-1) + \Theta(n),
$$
which has solution $T(n) = \Theta(n^2)$.

Comment: Nobody asked for the worst case.

Comment: @gnasher729, Indeed. They asked for a $O(n^2)$ upper bound on the average case, and I'm noting that a $O(n^2)$ upper bound on the worst case already provides the sought upper bound on the average case. Then I'm showing how such worst-case upper bound can be obtained.

Comment: gnasher729 $O$-Notation is an asymptotic upper bound. An asymptotic upper bound for the worst-case-runtime must also be an asymptotic upper bound for the expected runtime.

Answer (score 1):

It’s a trick question...

O(f(n)) doesn’t only contain functions that grow about as fast as f(n), it also contains all the functions that grow a lot slower than f(n).

So the average time for quicksort is O(n log n), but it is also O(n^2), O(n^5), O(n!) and many other functions.